Iterate data pandas between two tables
I'm trying to add a new column to my customers table (table). This new column is the sum of pending orders for a product (SKU). Pending orders are in another table (tableOV). I managed to do this, but it is taking a long time to calculate. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way.
table
[]
tableOV
[]
table with new pendent sum column
[]
my code
table = pd.DataFrame(productsCustomerCd)

tableOV['CC'] = tableOV['CC'].astype(str)
tableOV['SKU'] = tableOV['SKU'].astype(str)
table['cc'] = table['cc'].astype(str)

sumPendentList = []
for i in table.itertuples():
    sumPendent = tableOV.loc[(tableOV['CC']==i.cc)].loc[(tableOV['SKU']==i.sku), 'Pendent'].sum()
    sumPendentList.append(sumPendent)

    print(i.cc, i.sku, sumPendent)

table['Pendent'] = sumPendentList

print(table)

I'm trying to add a new column to my customers table (table). This new column is the sum of pending orders for a product (SKU). Pending orders are in another table (tableOV). I managed to do this, but it is taking a long time to calculate. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way.

Why is Pendent columns looks all he value is zero? Is it expected?

Yes, as there are customers who do not have a pending

Sure, it is preferable to perform group by CC and SKU on the tableOV, compute the sum  and then merge with the table dataframe. A code like this should do the work:
sumPendent = tableOV.groupby(['CC','SKU'])['Pendent'].sum().reset_index()
sumPendent.columns=['CC','SKU','Sum of pendent']
final_table = table.merge(sumPendent,left_on=['cc','sku'],right_on=['CC','SKU'],how='left')

If you have CC or SKU that are in table but not in tableOV, they will have NaN values in the added column. If you want to assume they have no pendent orders then you can just add
final_table['Sum of pendent'] = final_table['Sum of pendent'].fillna(0)


I used this code, but final_table is not associating. It is having NaN results, both for column 'CC' and 'SKU'. I used how='inner', and it brought me what I expected, but it excluded the lines from customers that don't have a pending item. I would like it to appear as 0.

I put how=outer, and it returned what I wanted

If this solution solved your question, please accept it which confirms resolution to future readers.
